# How does python return list from functions? List passed is immutable?

Tags: python

```
def insertion_sort(A):
    for j in range(1, len(A)):
        key = A[j]
    i = j - 1
    while (i >= 0) and (A[i] > key):
        A[i+1] = A[i]
        i = i-1
    A[i+1] = key

    return A


print insertion_sort([8, 1, 3, 4, 9, 5, 2])
```

Now this prints: `[8, 1, 3, 4, 9, 5, 2]`

But I assume, I am mutating the list A, then why is the return value the same?

Comment: Please fix the indenting on your code in the question. Currently your first for loop just reduces to `key=A[len(A)-1]`. I'm hoping your actual problem isn't just indentation (if it is, fix that).

Comment: If `insertion_sort()` modifies `A` inplace then it should return `None` to signal that. Compare `list.sort()` vs. `sorted()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is wrong with current indentation. It should be like this, right?

```
def insertion_sort(A):
    for j in range(1, len(A)):
        key = A[j]
        i = j - 1
        while (i >= 0) and (A[i] > key):
            A[i+1] = A[i]
            i = i-1
        A[i+1] = key

    return A
```

Comment: I used vim to autoformat the code: gg=G and it messed it up! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the indentation is incorrect.

And lists are mutable!